# jQuery UI code problem in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a script that works great in FF and Safari, but does not display properly in IE. There's gotta be some sort of error somewhere but I can't seem to be able to find it...

Here's the URL: http://www.k8r.me/AYXybP

Try dragging boxes from the left pane into the right area in FF or Safari. Compare with IE...

Is there a good tool to help me debug these sort of issues? Did I miss something?

I'd really appreciate another set of eyes taking a look at the source.

Comment: Wow, apparently IE does not like my doctype. I have <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> and the problem exists in quirks mode... Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer's Developer Tools (press F12) are a decent debugging tool for these issues. IE9 debugger shows two errors:

> Line: 89 Character: 3 Code: 0 Error Message: Expected identifier,
>   string or number URL: http://www.c8r.us/jq/dragdrop-client.js
>
> Line: 314 Character: 3 Code: 0 Error Message: Expected identifier,
>   string or number URL: http://www.c8r.us/ux4RJSC

One error is here:

```
function stackClose(stackId)
{
    var s = $("#" + stackId);

    if( s.hasClass("empty") )
        deleteEmptyStack(s);
    else {
        $("#cantDelStack").dialog({
            modal:      true,
            draggable:  false,
            resizable:  false,
            width:      300,
            buttons: {
                "OK":   function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
            },
        });
    }
}
```

fix:

```
function stackClose(stackId)
{
    var s = $("#" + stackId);

    if( s.hasClass("empty") ){
        deleteEmptyStack(s);
    } else {
        $("#cantDelStack").dialog({
            modal:      true,
            draggable:  false,
            resizable:  false,
            width:      300,
            buttons: {
                "OK":   function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think the issue may have been the comma after the `buttons` object. IE is finicky like that.

Comment: You're right! I thought I fixed that one way back when but somehow I propagated it again... Thanks.

Comment: @santa Glad you got it fixed.